# Google Chrome Install gives errors

Tags: software-installation

When I try and install Google Chrome using the terminal I get the following

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
How can I overcome this problem. My machine is 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

with this output i would try

```
sudo dpkg --no-act --configure  -a
```

To see if the system want to do something and if I like what it outputs

```
sudo dpkg --configure  -a
```

`

Comment: I did the first command you suggested and got

Comment: roger@roger-MS-7994:~$ sudo dpkg --no-act --configure  -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable

Comment: I then tried to install and got  roger@roger-MS-7994:~$ sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libappindicator1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
roger@roger-MS-7994:~$ 
What do I do to sort this out?

Comment: did you update the apt before running the install?
`sudo apt-get update && sudo dpkg --no-act --configure -a`'